# Which database to use- Mysql or Oracle?

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

If someone is to build a University Management System using PHP, which database would you suggest for that- Mysql or Oracle? Or let me put it this way.. is it okay if someone uses mysql as a database for the University Management System or it is better to use Oracle?

Thanks in Advance

EDIT

Sorry, I should have been more specific about the University management system. What the plan is, to store student, teacher, employees information. Enroll Students in courses(students will hook up online and do it by themselves). All students,teachers and employees will have own personalized page. Some other features are fee collection, library management, attendance tracking etc.

Thanks :)

Comment: Both databases are absolutely OK. This mostly depends on personal opinion, experience and so on :)

Comment: They each have their advantages and disadvantages. Work out what you want from the database and research which serves your purpose best.

Comment: I think you are going to have to provide more information than this.  How many tables?  How much data?  Ingestion rates?  Number of concurrent users?  Reliability requirements?  What level of technical support do you require?  The question is just too broad.

Comment: That's an extremely broad, vague question that is difficult to prudently answer without knowing requirements, constraints, etc. Specific questions would be needed. In theory either DB could work, ultimately you'll have to decide that with your requirements and research due diligence.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, MySQL is powerful enough for most things. If you're looking for data storage, then MySQL will do the job. If you're going to be doing a lot of clustering, replication, stored procedures, triggers, and integration with enterprise software such as PeopleSoft, then Oracle may be a better solution.

It's a rather hard question to answer with out knowing how the database will be utilized.

In my experience I have used MySQL clustered and replicated across time zones with high traffic social networks, and have had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your PHP application using the PDO library for your database access, then your application will be able to work with either MySQL or Oracle (or several other DBs) without having to change the code.

However, if you have to make a choice over database now, then between these two it comes down to cost: MySQL is free; Oracle costs money. Quite a lot of money.

There's nothing wrong with MySQL as a database. It is capable of running high performance, high volume systems. There are advantages to using a commercial database like Oracle though (they wouldn't be able to justify the price otherwise).

(By the way, as an aside, it's worth knowing that the Oracle company also owns MySQL. So in fact both databases are produced by the same company)